# Blank Window while program is running?

Tags: c++

```
//***********************************************************

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

// function prototypes
void intOutput();
void floatingPointOutput();
void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width); // int math demonstration
void writeHeaderLine(int width);
void writeMathLine(int a, int b, int width);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a, b, width, rows;

cout << "\nProject 1: Math and Functions";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nProject 1 Start.";
cout << "\nZack Cunningham";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nInteger Output Demo:";
cout << "\n";

intOutput();
floatingPointOutput();
intMathOperations(rows, b, width); // int math demonstration
writeHeaderLine(width);
writeMathLine(a, b, width);

cout << "\n";
cout << "\nProject 1 End.";
cout << "\n";

const int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
intMathOperations(12, 5, FIELD_WIDTH);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void intMathOperations(int rows, int b, int width){
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nInteger Math Operations Demo:";
cout << "\n";
writeHeaderLine(width);
cout << "\n";
for (int a = 0; a < rows; ++a){writeMathLine(a, b, width);
}
}


void writeHeaderLine(int width){
cout << "\n";
cout << setw(width) << "a";
cout << setw(width) << "b";
cout << setw(width) << "a * b";
cout << setw(width) << "a / b";
cout << setw(width)<< "a % b";
}

void writeMathLine(int a, int b, int width){
cout << setw(width) << a;
int rows;
for (int a = 0; a < rows; ++a){writeMathLine(a, b, width);
}
}

void floatingPointOutput(){
double a = 2000;
double b = 3;
double c = a / b;
cout << "\n" << a << " / " << b << " = ";
cout << "\n" << c;

cout << setprecision(10);
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << scientific; // scientific notation
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << fixed; // standard decimal notation
cout << "\n" << setw(20)<< c;
cout << left; // left justify
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << right;

// right justify (default)
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << setprecision(6); // return to default
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << c;
cout << "\n";
}

// function calls
void intOutput(){
cout << "\nInteger Output Demo:";
cout << "\n";
int a = 12;
int b = 12345678;
cout << "\n....5...10...15...20"; // spacing info
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << b;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(4) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(4) << b;
cout << left; // left justified
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << a;
cout << "\n" << setw(20) << b;
cout << right; // right (default) justified
cout << "\n";
}
```

This is all my code for my program, and I have worked on it over, and over. And finally have no errors, but it's a blank program that is just running in an infinite loop. I'm unsure of what to do, if anyone could help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I suggest cutting down your program to be as simple as possible before posting and making sure your indents are correct.  You should also clarify what you mean by its being a blank program.  Do you really mean that it doesn't output anything, including "Project 1: Math and Functions"?

Comment: Please only include the code relevant  to your question, no one really wants to read through your entire program

Comment: You might want to increase the warning level of the compiler and pay attention to the uninitialized variable warnings.

Comment: Looks like most of your variables are used without being initialized ( variables passed to `intMathOperations`). *don't do that*.

Comment: Alright, my bad I'll try to shorten it next time and format it better. And I'll try to debug my code better.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: and no it won't output anything, the scroll bar just keeps going down and down and the program interface is all black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you need to fix this. You defined variable `rows` as

```
int a, b, width, rows;
```

But you did not initialize `rows` and you used it here,

```
intMathOperations(rows, b, width); // int math demonstration
```

which used `rows` in a `for` loop as the ending condition.  This is a problem.

To fix this I would suggest you turn on all the warnings like this

```
g++ -Wall your_code.cpp
```

And make sure you understand every warning you have and fix the necessary ones.

Comment: He did not initialize `b` and `width` either, he only created local variables

Comment: This is one of very many issues that the compiler is capable of pointing out.

Comment: yes, you are right there are a few more variables need to be initialized.